# How to calculate column in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Where in my application i am binding products table to gridview then when i enter the quantity in the quantity column it should calculate with the price and display the total in the total column. How can i do this in gridview.

Comment: `dgv[0,1].Value = CalculatePrice(Convert.ToInt32(gdv[0,0].Value));`

Comment: where is your efforts ??

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
decimal a=0, b=0, c=0;

for (int i = 0; i < (gridview1.Rows.Count); i++)
           {
               a = Convert.ToDecimal(gridview1.Rows[i].Cells["Column Index"].Text.ToString());
               c = c + a; //storing total qty into variable 
}
```

hope this help u..